# choose column to display phpmyadmin WAMP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

For some reason I can see the "choose column to display" under relation view? I am running WAMP and my version of phpmyadmin is version: 5.6.17

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean you are using WAMPServer 2,5 with MySQL 5.6.17 and phpMyAdmin 4.1.14. Please can you be more precise with your question. It sounds like this question is `to broad` and `off topic` but if you make an effort to make the question understandable, maybe you wont get this question closed for those reasons.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?